# Getting QueryStrings from WebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, request.querystring

Lets say i have this:

```
WebRequest myWebRequest1 = (WebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
```

i know that i can get the url like this `myWebRequest1.RequestUri` but i was wondering if there is any way to get the query strings using a better way than manualy parsing it , i mean something like `myWebRequest1.QueryString[etc etc ]`

any ideas ?

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try extracting the request URI as a string and using:  [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)